# Farcry 3 randomly enters windowed mode

Tags: pc, far-cry-3

For starters, whenever I face a tiger, game goes windowed mode. After that, whenever I press Z to use the camera (or to take it off) it also changes to windowed mode.

I've tried to set the camera key to the key next to 0, but when I press it, it still happens.

Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I pressed once the windows key, and suddenly the game changed the mode to windowed (even if I set fullscreen with alt+enter, game still says it's in windowed mode).

I have to change it in the video settings.

Comment: The windows key is the bane of many gamers... you can however [disable it completely](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216893) if you wish.

Comment: Nah, just once. In fact when a game crashes sometimes the windows key is a way out, and practically better than the fullscreening ctrl+alt+supr version of win7

Answer (score 1):

If I were to venture a guess, it sounds like your computer is communicating with another program, causing the other program to become the focus, forcing your game into windowed mode. You could try closing other programs, perhaps an overlay program such as Steam or Overwolf could cause this. There are any number of programs that actively listen for hotkeys, such as Skype or Teamspeak.

Comment: It wasn't any of these programs, but I bet it was because I pressed once the windows key, and suddenly the game changed the mode to windowed (even if I set fullscreen with alt+enter, game still says it's in windowed mode). You have to change it in the settings.